# How to read mips assembly generated by gcc '-dap -S'

Tags: gcc, assembly, mips

```
  bne $2,$0,$L4  # 27 *branch_equalitydi  [length = 8]
  lw  $4,$LC0  # 29 *movsf_softfloat/2  [length = 24]
  move  $5,$0  # 30 *movsf_softfloat/1  [length = 4]
  jal __divsf3   # 31 call_value_internal/2 [length = 8]
```

What I do understand is that its the following pattern :

```
opcode $dest, $src1, $src2 # insn_uid * md-pattern/XX  [length = XX]
```

What I dont understand is the XX part in the pattern. Can someone shed some light on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the source, Luke! The relevant part in `gcc` source code is:

```
  if (insn_data[num].n_alternatives > 1)
    fprintf (asm_out_file, "/%d", which_alternative + 1);
```

The instruction templates may provide multiple alternatives for various circumstances, and this number tells you which one has been used. Let's look at the definition for `movsf_softfloat`:

```
(define_insn "*movsf_softfloat"
  [(set (match_operand:SF 0 "nonimmediate_operand" "=d,d,m")
        (match_operand:SF 1 "move_operand" "Gd,m,d"))]
```

As you can see, it provides 3 alternatives. `lw $4,$LC0` was a move from memory into a register described by the second set of constraints (`d` and `m`). `move $5,$0` was a register-to-register move, described by the first alternative (`d` and `Gd`). There is also a third alternative, which is a move from a register to memory. This is also indicated by the `move_type` attribute which is set as: `set_attr "move_type" "move,load,store"`.